# facebook doesn't show image dynamically

Tags: php, facebook

it shows title and descriptions on fb but doesn't show image. every time I need to debug on facebook. I built a custom news portal which shows every post dynamically. such as id=200. in this case facebook doesn't refresh and take my new one. I have to go to facebook developer to everytime to debug my post that is not possible always to go to debug. how I want facebook to crul my every post. I used og: image and title properly.

Please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: og tags are not meant to be dynamic. you should use a different url each time.

Comment: thank you. I used php and called my id in url but it's not working.

Comment: "not working" is not a sufficient error description. please be more specific, if the id does not change then the og tags will not change magically either. again, og tags are not meant to be dynamic.

Comment: <meta property="og:title"content="<?php echo $row->title ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="150">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="100">
<meta property="og:image"content="http://www.jaintanews24.com/<?php echo $row->image ?>"/>
<meta property="og:description"content="<?php echo $row->description ?>"/>  is not the correct way to do that? I have no way to do that instead of it because my every page and post is dynamic. everything is showing from database. please help it there is any alternative way.

Comment: 150x100? you should check out the facebook docs for image size recommendations, it should be 1200x630. anyway, what is $row->image? is that an id? can you add an example link? the og image only changes if the parameters are different. if you want to have a DIFFERENT image for the SAME url, then you would need to rescrape the whole time, which is pointless.

Comment: thank you Mr luschn. $row->image is the showing object like mysql_fetch_object from my database. I studied and gave image different image size but it doesn't work. when I go to facebook debug and search that  shows me my image and title everything correctly. $row->image echo image image from database for example download.jpg. thanks again

Comment: Please help me to do that. Still I can not solve this problem

Comment: a test link would be neccessary.